# log4j.properties output FileName configuration should be : path+DD-MM-AAAA - Filename.log

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to have a log output file with a path like .log/ DD-MM-AAAA - Filename.log

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - logTest.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Actually it doesn't work. If I remove **%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}** the output is : logs/logTest.log
But i need to have the date on my output file name.

What I want is :logs/DD-MM-YYYY - logTest.log

Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: The built-in file appenders do not provide such option. So if you want date in your logfile name, you would have to create your own FileAppender by extending FileAppender class. Or as @Amol answered, just use the DatePattern, wait for a day to get the file name with date appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below snippet, it will add date to generated log file next day.

```
# configure the root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DAILY, stdout
#configure the daily rolling file appender
log4j.appender.DAILY=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.DAILY.File=/opt/ZudioFeedbackApplication/log/zudio.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.DAILY.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm} [%p] %c:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

The Generated log file will be like. 
`zudio.log` (you can change name and path), and next day it will rename itself with `zudio.log.2019-11-19`. For your requirement try it by changing `DatePattern`

Comment: is it possible to check if it's work without waiting 00h01?